# How to output multiple notes (chords) from Bitwig grid?

Tags: bitwig-grid

I want to create a note-grid that outputs chords, but I seem to only be able to output one voice at at time.  How can I output multiple?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is actually surprisingly simple.  You can have multiple note out modules, and each will represent a different voice.

[image: multiple note outs]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the other answer addressed your question, but if you were wondering the same thing I was, this may be helpful to you: in the Device settings control that comes up when you double-click the Poly Grid instrument, there's a **Voices** option that's initially set to `Mono`.  Spinning it up (to 4 in my case) made my Grid instrument polyphonic.

[image: screenshot of Device settings, cursor hovering on Voices setting]

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thanks!